# PDF from Httpresponse

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I am trying to get a pdf from a httpresponse.  Currently I am doing this by:

```
public Blob getPDF(){

Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
String url = '...endpoint that would go here...';
String soapXML = '...string that would go here...';
req.setBody(soapXML);
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(soapXML.length()));
req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/pdf');
req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'assume the correct action here');

HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
String xml = res.getBody();

Blob retBlob = res.getBodyAsBlob();
String retContentFile = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(retBlob);

system.debug(xml);
System.debug(retContentFile);
System.debug(retBlob);        
return retBlob;

}
```

And from my visualforce page A I have a button that opens a new window to a visualforce page B:

```
<script>
function previewPDF(){
    window.open("/apex/PDFPReview");
    }
</script>
<apex:commandButton value="Preview PDF" onClick="previewPDF();" />
```

And on the visualforce page B (PDFPReview) I have:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="VSController" contentType="application/pdf">
      <script>
            window.location.href = "data&colon;application/pdf;base64,{!PDF}";
      </script>
</apex:page>
```

When the PDF preview page launches, it says:

> Failed to load PDF document.

So I am wondering if my problem is in the code above or does it have to do with the SOAPxml response I am getting back from my endpoint?

PS: I have tried returning xml, retContentFile, retBlob, and res

Edit:

Request:

```
Boolean isDevTest = True;
    String fedexUserKey;
    String fedexUserPassword;
    String clientDetailAccNum;
    String clientDetailMeterNumber;

    if (isDevTest) {
        AccountNumber = '#####';
        fedexUserKey = '#####';
        fedexUserPassword = '#####';
        clientDetailAccNum = '#####';
        clientDetailMeterNumber ='#####';
    } else {
        AccountNumber = '#####';
        fedexUserKey = '#####';
        fedexUserPassword = '#####';
        clientDetailAccNum = '#####';
        clientDetailMeterNumber ='#####';
    }
    String shipperName = '#####';
    String shipperCompany = '#####';
    String shipperPhone = '#####';
    String shipperEmail = '#####';
    String shipperStreetLines = '1202 Chalet Ln';
    String shipperCity = 'Harrison';
    String shipperStateOrProvinceCode = 'AR';
    String shipperPostalCode = '72601';
    String shipperCountryCode = 'US';
    String recipientName = 'John';
    String recipientCompany = 'None';
    String recipientPhone = '84375432';
    String recipientEmail = '#####';
    String recipientStreetLines = '2000 Freight LTL Testing';
    String recipientCity = 'Harrison';
    String recipientStateOrProvinceCode = 'AR';
    String recipientPostalCode = '72601';
    String recipientCountryCode = 'US';
    String contactName = 'John';
    String contactEmail = 'john@john.com';
    String weight = '2';
    String dimensionLength = '3';
    String dimensionWidth = '3';
    String dimensionHeight = '3';
    String ItemDescription = 'Nothing';

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    String url = 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship';
    String soapXML = ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v17"><SOAP-ENV:Header>' + 
                      '</SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ProcessShipmentRequest><WebAuthenticationDetail><UserCredential><Key>' + fedexUserKey + '</Key><Password>' 
                      + fedexUserPassword + '</Password></UserCredential></WebAuthenticationDetail><ClientDetail><AccountNumber>' + clientDetailAccNum + 
                      '</AccountNumber><MeterNumber>' + clientDetailMeterNumber + 
                      '</MeterNumber></ClientDetail><TransactionDetail><CustomerTransactionId>Ship_International_basic</CustomerTransactionId></TransactionDetail>' + 
                      '<Version><ServiceId>ship</ServiceId><Major>17</Major><Intermediate>0</Intermediate><Minor>0</Minor></Version><RequestedShipment>' + 
                      '<ShipTimestamp>2014-06-17T12:34:56-06:00</ShipTimestamp><DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType><ServiceType>FEDEX_GROUND</ServiceType>' + 
                      '<PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</PackagingType><Shipper><Contact><PersonName>' + shipperName + 
                      '</PersonName><CompanyName>' + shipperCompany + '</CompanyName><PhoneNumber>' + shipperPhone + 
                      '</PhoneNumber><EMailAddress>' + shipperEmail + '</EMailAddress></Contact><Address><StreetLines>' + shipperStreetLines + 
                      '</StreetLines><City>' + shipperCity + '</City><StateOrProvinceCode>' + shipperStateOrProvinceCode + 
                      '</StateOrProvinceCode><PostalCode>' + shipperPostalCode + '</PostalCode><CountryCode>' + shipperCountryCode + 
                      '</CountryCode></Address></Shipper><Recipient><Contact><PersonName>' + recipientName + 
                      '</PersonName><CompanyName>' + recipientCompany + '</CompanyName><PhoneNumber>' + recipientPhone + 
                      '</PhoneNumber><EMailAddress>' + recipientEmail + '</EMailAddress></Contact><Address><StreetLines>' + recipientStreetLines + 
                      '</StreetLines><StreetLines>' + recipientStreetLines + '</StreetLines><City>' + recipientCity + 
                      '</City><StateOrProvinceCode>' + recipientStateOrProvinceCode + '</StateOrProvinceCode><PostalCode>' + recipientPostalCode + 
                      '</PostalCode><CountryCode>' + recipientCountryCode + '</CountryCode></Address></Recipient><ShippingChargesPayment><PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>' + 
                      '<Payor><ResponsibleParty><AccountNumber>' + AccountNumber + '</AccountNumber><Contact><PersonName>' + contactName + 
                      '</PersonName><EMailAddress>' + contactEmail + '</EMailAddress></Contact></ResponsibleParty></Payor></ShippingChargesPayment>' + 
                      '<LabelSpecification><LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</LabelFormatType><ImageType>PNG</ImageType></LabelSpecification><RateRequestTypes>LIST' + 
                      '</RateRequestTypes><PackageCount>1</PackageCount><RequestedPackageLineItems><SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber><Weight><Units>LB</Units><Value>' + Weight + 
                      '</Value></Weight><Dimensions><Length>' + dimensionLength + 
                      '</Length><Width>' + dimensionWidth + '</Width><Height>' + dimensionHeight + 
                      '</Height><Units>IN</Units></Dimensions><PhysicalPackaging>BAG</PhysicalPackaging><ItemDescription>' + ItemDescription + 
                      '</ItemDescription><CustomerReferences><CustomerReferenceType>CUSTOMER_REFERENCE</CustomerReferenceType><Value>NAFTA_COO</Value></CustomerReferences>' + 
                      '</RequestedPackageLineItems></RequestedShipment></ProcessShipmentRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');
```

Above is the soapXMl request with ##### censoring information.

Response is an xml, (with an LOTS OF CHARACTERS) so how do I get it to pdf?

Comment: Would content-type for your request really be application/pdf ? Wouldn't it be whatever it should be for SOAP XML? Be interested to see the output of xml string.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to successfully use a data URI as the SRC to an iframe (which is similar to what you are trying to do), e.g.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:iframe height="500px" width="1000px" src="{!content}"/>
```

**Controller**

```
public String getContent() {
    PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/TestPage');
    Blob contentData = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
    return 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentData);     
}
```

So, whilst I appreciate you are receiving your PDF from a SOAP webservice, my point is that it should be possible to use a data URI, but I think something is going awry with your response.

**EDIT** Your XML response shows you are not working with PDF:

The response from your web service is SOAP XML, you need to [parse that response using the DOM Parser](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring10/XML+DOM+Parsing) and eventually retrieve the String values for the following xpath:

```
SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ProcessShipmentReply/CompletedPackageDetails/OperationalDetail/Label/Parts/Image
```

This element contains Base64 encoded String that represents a Freight Label. In addition to this, the value in `ImageType` also tells you that this is an Image file (PNG), rather than a PDF. So, in building your data URI you would need to build it as follows:

```
public String getImageBase64() {
    String imageData = getImage(); // parse the XML and retrieve the String in Image
    return 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;
}
```

Note the change from application/pdf to image/png.

Comment: I've added the SoapXML request to the question, however cannot add the response due to potentially confidential information.

Comment: The answer probably lies in the response. As I said, you can't convert XML to a PDF, its likely the data you're after is in your response.

Comment: Here is a link to the response: http://justpaste.it/qglz

Answer (score 0):

You can't "rerender" a PDF using content from a blob. A blob can contain a great variety of information in various formats. You also can't re-render an existing PDF using `renderAsPDF`. Any images have to be in standard JPG, PNG, GIF,etc formats that the SF PDF Render engine knows how to process. It doesn't know what to do with a blob.

Comment: I think in theory they should be able to do what they are trying to...they are trying to use a data URI to display the PDF so not sure the "SF PDF Render engine" comes into it does it??

Comment: Wait, is he just trying to display it? If I've misread, then yes, he should be able to display another PDF in-line. He just can't re-render it as another PDF.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the PDF was actually a PNG. Imagine my happiness when I'm fiddling around with code and finally receive what I want because of a random guess.

Answer is here:

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="FedExController">
    <img src="data:/image/png;base64,{!PDF}" />
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
return pdf;
```